# Generate list string based on replacement possibility

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, parsing, csv

I'm doing an basic CSV import/export in C#. Most of it is really simple and basic, we just have one speciality.

In values we import/export, we have some specials values, which are not ASCII values. To ease the work of our end users, the customer decided to convert some values in some other values and do the opposite when importing.

Some examples

```
Value in our application   |  ValueS that must be accepted on parsing
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
³ | 3, ^3, **3
μ | u
₃ | 3
⁹ | 9
° | deg
φ | phi
```

To export, it's easy, we replace the matching character by the first on the second column.

But for the parsing, it's more complicated, and I don't see an easy way to get all the possible values to import?

One example:

```
H³ 3° (asd)₃
```

Would be exported as

```
H3 3deg (asd)3
```

So to parse this correctly, I've to get all the possibilities:

- `H3 3deg (asd)3` //This may be a real values
- `H³ 3deg (asd)3`
- `H₃ 3deg (asd)3`
- `H3 ³deg (asd)3`
- ....

What would be the good way of doing this?

Comment: During export you can replace anything what is not ASCII with something like `{unicode:12311}`.

Comment: If you import H3 would this be `H³` or `H₃` ? or `H3` ? Your encoding is lacking information, it is a lossy encoding which encodes several inputs to the same output. It is thus not reversible. You need to find a different way to encode this in order to differentiate between the inputs.

Comment: Also, it is not clear what you're asking here. Are you asking how to decode correctly (impossible) or what is the best way (lacking information, like probabilities and whether it is allowed to decode incorrectly)?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it's possible with such an encoding. All `H3` values are equally likely unless there is a rule that differentiates them. This makes parsing more difficult, not less.

What you are trying to do though looks a lot like what has already been done with tools like Latex or even Word. You should probably use the encodings used by Latex since they've already done the work of encoding symbols to human readable and editable keywords that can be parsed easily, eg: use `^` for power, `_` for indices, `\degree` for degrees, etc.

In fact, even Word allows these same keywords nowadays in the Math editor, allowing you to type `\sum` and get ∑, or `\oint` for ∮

You should probably tag the fields that contain substitutions, eg by surrounding them in multiple braces, so that users can use the keywords in their own text.

Comment: I've a closed set of values(a big set, but closed one). I can guarantee 100% that when we export, with the replaced char, it makes an unique meaningfull values for us

Comment: What is the problem then? If `H3` is unique, why is it difficult to decode it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to exclude ambiguous mappings. E.g.:

```
³ | ^3, **3
₃ | 3
⁹ | ^9, **9
```

or

```
³ | 3, ^3, **3
₃ | _3
⁹ | 9
```

Answer (score 0):

ASCII has 7 Bits for each character. Now you want to use chars which are implemented in the space of 8 Bits (UTF8 for example).

Now you lose information by converting your UTF8 character to ASCII but you want get back the full information.

To manage this, you need a mask, which helps to recognize the right character.

You could use [special characters](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php) as your mask. So you don't reinvent the wheel and others can find the documentation all over the internet for your interface.

But if you make ³ => 3, you lose information (3 superscript => 3; where is the superscript and how you should guess the right choice?)

Comment: This doesn't respond to my question at all. I'm well aware of encoding issues, this is not the point. Having those replacement values is a requirement. This has been decided(not for me), to help our users(because UTF8 is not the default excel value, because not all users now how to type a `μ`, ...

Comment: ASCII has 8 bits, not 7. UTF8 uses 8-32 bits  - 8 only if the character is one of the first 127 ASCII characters, 16 or more in other cases

Comment: You're right. I googled it shortly and is not relevant to the problem.